# Reordering the children inside the StackPanel ? Win8

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I am swapping the two children inside of a stack panel by removing and adding the element at desired position(insert method).But removing and adding the elements causes memory address problem and app crashes as soon as i access the Element which was swapped.Is there any other way i can achieve swapping without "Removing and Adding" in StackPanel?

Win8+XAML+C#.

code snippet :

```
    UIElementCollection children = stack_map.Children;

    int i = children.IndexOf(stack_listView);                                
    StackPanel sp = children[i] as StackPanel;

    int j = children.IndexOf(mapPageInstance);                                
    MapPage mp = children[j] as MapPage;

    stack_map.Children.Remove(sp);
    stack_map.Children.Insert(1, sp);
```

I want to position 'sp' from zero index to first index in stack_map.

'mapPageInstance' is an instance of a custom Map Class(basically a map)

Comment: Could you post a code snippet which shows the problem? Removing and re-inserting an element should not cause any problems

Answer (score 0):

To swap the elements in your stackpanel above, I'd just use the following:

```
stack_map.Children.Remove(stack_listView);
stack_map.Children.Insert(1, stack_listView);
```

Of course, it implies that you have more than one item in your stackpanel.

There should not be any problems/memory errors after the swap if you continue to access stackpanel items by name rather than by index

Comment: doesnt work this way either.Crash happens in touch mode of simulator and on Surface but NOT on Desktop.Strange.Any other suggestion ?